# Makefile C in linux

Tags: c, makefile

I have 3 functions separated in .c files and the main.c I would like to make the make file, I wrote in the file:

```
# Indicate that the compiler is the gcc compiler

CC=gc

# Indicate to the compiler to include header files in the local folder
CPPFLAGS = -I

main: method1.o
main: method2.o
main: method3.o
main: method4.o
main.o: main.h
```

Whereas method 1,2,3,4 is the functions of the main .c and I have the following problem when I type make in the shell:

```
make
gcc  -I  -c -o method1.o method1.c
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [method1.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please post here your makefile too and have a look at C compilation process here http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html. Functions inside a file don't get converted to one .o file.

Comment: `gc` is not the GCC compiler. It's something else.

Comment: Also I can't see where are you compiling main.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CC=gcc
CPPFLAGS=-I include
VPATH=src include
main: main.o method1.o method2.o method3.o method4.o -lm
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
main.o: main.c main.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
method1.o: method1.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
method2.o: method2.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
method3.o: method3.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
method4.o: method4.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
```

it worked like this

Answer (score 1):

if your project contains the following files: `method1.c`  `method2.c`  `method3.c`  `method4.c` and `main.c`

you can use the following make file

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/header/files
CC=gcc
all: main

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS)  -c -o $@ $^

main: method1.o method2.o method3.o method4.o main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: The `%.o: %.c` rule is not needed, because it is provided by default.

Comment: @DietrichEpp also the `$(CPPFLAGS)` is included by dfault in this default rule ?. Because `CPPFLAGS` contains customized variable `-I/path/to/header/files`.

Comment: The default rule is `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<`, so your missing some flags.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `CPPFLAGS` definition:

```
# Indicate to the compiler to include header files in the local folder
CPPFLAGS = -I
```

According to the comment above it, it misses a `.`:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I.
```

Otherwise, `gcc` will treat the `-c` that comes after `-I` in your command line as the name of a directory where it can search for headers. Thus, as far as `gcc` is concerned there's no `-c` *option*, and it will attempt to link `method1.c` as a complete application, hence the error message complaining that there's no `main` function.

Comment: # Indicate that the compiler is the gcc compiler
CC = gcc
# Indicate to the compiler to include header files in folder include
CPPFLAGS = -I include
# Indicate to the compiler to look for source files and header files
# under folders "src" and "include"
VPATH = src include

Sort: main.o algorithms.o functions.o
 $(CC) $^ -o $@
main.o: main.c algorithms.h functions.h
 $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
algorithms.o: algorithms.c algorithms.h
 $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
functions.o: functions.c functions.h
 $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@